# What is unorderable types: int() < _LocIndexer()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

```
>top=int(top)
 well_blocks_in_Y=int(well_blocks_in_Y)
 right=int(right)
 left=int(left)
 ty=0
 ls=[]
 for i in range (len(df_main)):
     if (df_main.Y.loc[i] < (top-well_blocks_in_Y) and (left) < df_main.X.loc < (right-1)):
         for j in range(well_blocks_in_Y):
             ty = ty + df_main.Ranking.loc[(i+(j*(right-left)))]
             ty = ty + df_main.Ranking.loc[(i+(j*(right-left))-1)]
             ty = ty + df_main.Ranking.loc[(i-(j*(right-left))+1)]
          ls.append(ty)
          ty=0
     else:
          ls.append('')
 df_rank_y=pd.DataFrame(data=ls,index=None)
```

Error is

```
unorderable types: int() < _LocIndexer().
```

I get this while comparing a pandas df datatype `numpy.int64` with a user entered int data type.

Comment: Did you mean something like `df_main.X.loc[i] < (right-1)` instead of `df_main.X.loc < (right-1)`?

Answer (score 0):

df_main.X.loc[i] < (right-1) instead of df_main.X.loc < (right-1)
on line 8

Answer provided by Jean-François Fabre